Does random variable sequence with these conditions satisfy the Strong Law of Large Numbers?
Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of independent random variables with $EX_n=0$. And there is a constant $r>1$ making $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-(r+1)}{E\left(|X_n|^{2r}\right)}<\infty.$$
The question is if $\{X_n\}$ satisfy the Strong Law of Large Numbers, which means
$$\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n X_k\to 0\quad a.s?$$

I find this question difficult. For example, we can often prove strong LLM by proving that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty X_k/k$ is a.s. covergence. But if we let $X_1\equiv0$ and $X_k\sim N(0,n/\log n)\ for\ k>1$, it satisfies the conditions, and
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{X_k}{k}\sim N\left(0,\sum_{k=2}^n \frac1{k\log k}\right)\not\to\quad a.s.$$
because
$$ \sum_{k=2}^n \frac1{k\log k}\sim C\int_2^n\frac{\mathrm dx}{x\log x}\sim C \log \log n\to\infty $$
These means the common method is invalid. By the way,
$$ \frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n X_k\sim N\left(0,\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{k}{\log k}\right)$$
$$\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{k}{\log k}\sim \frac C{\log n}\to0$$

What is the meaning of $E|X_n|^{2r}$? Is it $E[|X_n|^{2r}]$ or $E[|X_n|]^{2r}$?

It is E(|X_n|^2r)

Are the ${X_n}$ identical?

@VarunVejalla Then the assumption $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-(r+1)}{E\left(|X_n|^{2r}\right)}<\infty$ would be the same as ${E\left(|X_1|^{2r}\right)}<\infty$, and the SLLN holds for for iid. random variables if only $\mathbb{E}[\vert X_1\vert] < \infty$.

@LasswetzPatz How do you conclude $\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n X_k\sim N\left(0,\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{k}{\log k}\right)\to0\quad a.s. $? A priori this convergence is only in probability, not almost surely, or not?

@unwissen Sorry, you are right. I made a mistake and haven't prove a.s. convergence. But that example still match the condition, so it still shows that the common method is impossible.
